# Assign filenames through the loop in SAS

Tags: loops, macros, sas, filenames

I have a list of files that I need to import into SAS. I need to assign filename so that I don't type multiples times the same lines:

```
filename inf_1_1 'C:\Users\Main_1\final_complete_1.1.csv';
filename inf_1_2 'C:\Users\Main_1\final_complete_1.2.csv';
```

I tried to write %macro but it does not recognize the file name:

```
%macro FILENAME (I_FROM=1, I_TO=&I_FROM, J_FROM=1, J_TO=&J_FROM);

 %local I J;

 %do I = &I_FROM %to &I_TO;
 %do J = &J_FROM %to &J_TO;

 filename inf_&I._&J. 'C:\Users\Main_&I.\final_complete_&I.&J.csv';

%end;
%end;

%mend;
%FILENAME(J_TO=2); */
```

I am sure I am doing smth wrong and need to take the filename out of the string variable. But I don't know how to do it.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You can read multiple files in a single step or you can read multiple files to multiple data sets but neither would use the approach above. You don't need a filename reference and if you want to create one for each file it's doable. I would use the data step function though instead, not open code method.

Comment: filename references are 8 characters though and you have a list of macro variables but only pass one in?

Comment: Hello Reeza, thank you for your comment. So I've created %macro import_main(inf,outdat) to import csv files. At first, I thought I should set up the infile name. That's why I need to create a list of filenames for each csv file.

Comment: nah, just pass the filename directly to the macro. You can use a data step here to call the macro, use call execute and use CATT functions to build your string.

Comment: I put a couple of options for you below but untested. If they don't work and you can't debug let me know. Here's one more method as well: https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/Import_all_files_one_type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the modifications below - basically reduce the filename string to import the data.

List of issues:

- Macro variables resolve only in double quotes, not single quotes
- Macro call - don't include the & in the macro definition
- FileRefs are limited to 8 characters
- FileRefs are not necessarily needed

  ```
   %macro FILENAME (I_FROM=1, I_TO=I_FROM, J_FROM=1, J_TO=J_FROM);

   %local I J;

    %do I = &I_FROM %to &I_TO;
    %do J = &J_FROM %to &J_TO;

   filename i_&I._&J. "C:\Users\Main_&I.\final_complete_&I.&J..csv";

   proc import out=data_&i._&j. datafile=i_&i._&j. dbms=csv; run;

  %end;
  %end;

  %mend;
  %FILENAME(I_FROM=1, I_TO=10, J_FROM=1, J_TO=2);
  ```

As mentioned you don't really need the filename reference.

```
%macro FILENAME (I_FROM=1, I_TO=I_FROM, J_FROM=1, J_TO=J_FROM);

 %local I J;

 %do I = &I_FROM %to &I_TO;
 %do J = &J_FROM %to &J_TO;


 proc import out=data_&i._&j. datafile="C:\Users\Main_&I.\final_complete_&I.&J..csv" dbms=csv; run;

%end;
%end;

%mend;
%FILENAME(I_FROM=1, I_TO=10, J_FROM=1, J_TO=2);
```

Last but not least, you don't need a macro here:

```
data _null_;
do i=1 to 2;
do j=1 to 2;
   *create filename;
   file_name = catt('C:\users_Main\Main_', i, '\final_complete_', i, '_', j, '.csv');
   *create output data set name;
   outdata = catt('data_', i, '_', j);
   *create command to import;
   str = catt('proc import out=', outdata, ' datafile=', filename, ' dbms=csv; run;');
call execute(str);
end;
end;
run;
```

Comment: Hello Reeza, thank you very much for the hints. I've re-written my code. Proc import won't work in my case but you provided amazing hints. My macro works now.

Comment: Glad it helped :). If you're using a data step: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/How-do-I-write-a-macro-to-import-multiple-text-files-that-have/ta-p/223627

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the hints. I've written the following macro:

```
 %macro Filename_loop (I_FROM=1, I_TO=&I_FROM, J_FROM=1, J_TO=&J_FROM);

 %local I J;

 %do I = &I_FROM %to &I_TO;
 %do J = &J_FROM %to &J_TO;

filename inf_&I._&J. "C:\Users\Main_&I.\final_complete_&I..&J..csv";


%end;
%end;

%mend;
%Filename_loop(J_TO=2);
```